# Why does Gremlin Query select/by errors out whereas querying by properties() returns fine?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

For the queries below against the **Tinkerpop's toy graph** (graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()), why does the first query returns fine (with the expected no results) but the second query errors out?

Query 1:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").has("name", "marko").properties("foo")
```

Query 2:

```
    gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("person").has("name", "marko").as("p").select("p").by("foo")
    org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.filter.HasStep 
cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.ByModulating
```

EDIT: Updated `by` to `as` - did not paste my original query correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is an error in Query 2 it should be `g.V().hasLabel("person").has("name", "marko").as("p").select("p").by("foo")`

Even with that the query will return an error becasue the vertex 'p' does not have a property 'foo'.  The reason this throws an error is that the `by` step is not an actual step in Gremlin it is a modulator on another step, in this case the `select("p")` step.  In Query 2 you are trying to modulate an element (v[1](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#by-step) in the modernGraph) by a non-existant property which results in an error.

In contrast Query 1 is trying to retrieve a property 'foo' from a map which is what the `properties` step returns.  In groovy (the underlying language of Gremlin) when you try to pull a non-existent property from a map a `null` is returned.

[Gremlin By Step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#by-step)

[Gremlin Properties Step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_properties_step)

Comment: Just curious, if I'm forced to use `select`/`by`, are there any modulator or steps to prevent the error and just return blank?